# Luminosity of beamdump experiments

Tags: particle-physics, collision, large-hadron-collider

There is formula for luminosity of fixed-target experiments:
$$L = \Phi\rho l$$
$\Phi$ is the flux of incoming beam (particles per second), $\rho$ - density of target, $l$ - lenght of target. We can see that if we increase $l$ up to infinity luminosity will increase to infinity as well. For me it doesnt seem right. As I understood flux in material is a function of depth $\Phi(d)$. This mean that luminosity should be something like this:
$$L = \int_{0}^{l} \rho \Phi(x)  \text dx$$
Like this luminosity should be finite value even if lenght is infinite. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: The first formula is for thin targets.

Comment: @KeithMcClary i see. Have you encountered formula for thick targets?

Comment: You would have to take in to account the decrease in flux with depth due to interactions.

Comment: With simplifying assumptions, the decrease in $\Phi(x)$ over $dx$ should be proportional to $\Phi(x)$.